# LIME - local linear explanations for global black-box models work for LogisticRegression but not for RandomForest?

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, prediction

I'm trying to use [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) to locally explain black-box models predictions. It works by generating 5000 neighbors for an instance by perturbing the features. Then it does `forward-selection` by iteratively fitting a simple `Ridge` model over that local neighborhood, where **the label is the black-box model prediction**. After 
n iterations, the selected features are considered as the most important for the black-box decision, and the weights are indicative of how important.

I'm measuring how good is that explanation by measuring the `R^2` of the local model.

When the black-box model is `LogisticRegression`, the average `R^2` is ~0.65 which I consider pretty good. However, once I switched to a more sophisticated `RandomForest` black-box model, I'm getting a very low (~0.06) mean `R^2` score.

Why is that? does that mean that the LIME method isn't good for explaining the surface of my model predictions?

---

Technicalities: I have 6 features -`age, gender, hemoglobin_last, hemoglobin_slope, creatinine_last and creatinine_slope` and the outcome I'm trying to predict is chronic_renal_failure. The data is pretty imbalanced: 1.5M controls and 5K cases. For measuring quality I randomly selected 100 cases and 100 controls and averaged the `R^2` score of their explanation.

(related to [Interpret predictions of black box models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269958/interpret-predictions-of-black-box-models))

Comment: I am getting similarly low results trying to explain my SVM classifier, haven't compared it to to another model though. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/vignettes/Understanding_lime.html) it is suggested to adjust the kernel width of the local model (decrease to make the fit more local). This seems to definitely change the $R^2$ values for me. Don't really know why the values differ so much for different models... Will post more if I get some more insights into it.